# Skipping an item from being checked in where clause

Tags: sql

In the code below, in the `WHERE` clause, all the items are checked against that condition `"bcp.value = cm.id"`. Hence if item has no value in bcp table it wont show up, how do i make it show up?
I have tried my best using the likes of sub query without success.
Please help

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
   u.firstname,
   u.lastname,
   u.id,
   c.shortname,
   c.fullname,
   cs.name AS 'Units Code/s Covered',
   m.name,


   MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(cmc.timemodified)) AS 'Start Time',
   MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(bgi.dateissued))AS 'Time Completed'

FROM
  mdl_course_modules_completion cmc

  LEFT JOIN mdl_course_modules cm
        ON (cmc.coursemoduleid =cm.id)

    LEFT JOIN mdl_course_sections cs 
        ON (cs.id = cm .section)

    LEFT JOIN mdl_modules m
        ON (m.id= cm.module )

 LEFT JOIN mdl_course c
        ON c.id = cm.course AND c.shortname = 'DOM_2015_1'
LEFT JOIN mdl_user u
        ON u.id = cmc.userid AND (u.firstname = 'bambo' OR u.firstname = 'Test bambo') 

LEFT JOIN mdl_badge_issued bgi
        ON bgi.userid = cmc.userid

LEFT JOIN mdl_badge bg
        ON bg.id = bgi.badgeid

LEFT JOIN mdl_badge_criteria bc
        ON bc.badgeid = bg.id

LEFT JOIN mdl_badge_criteria_param bcp
        ON bcp.critid = bc.id AND bcp.value = cm.id



GROUP BY u.firstname, cs.name, FROM_UNIXTIME(bgi.dateissued)
```

Comment: Move the WHERE conditions to ON clauses to get true outer join! (As it is now, it executes as regular inner joins for these tables...)

Comment: @The, was that a comment regarding my comment? Doesn't matter if it's a full, left or right outer join, a WHERE clause condition like above makes it execute as inner join.

Comment: Hi jarlh, Thanks for your time and help. Sorry, did you mean putting the where clause in ON clause? and have no WHERE clause at all?

Comment: No WHERE clause needed here, just move the one condition to the LEFT JOIN C ON clause, and the other one to the LEFT JOIN bcp ON clause! (And you'll get true left joins!)

Comment: Hi jarlh, I made the changes you suggested (see the code). It still doesn't work, doesn't match the completed dates with the completed modules :(

Comment: Sorry, my comment was just mean to be a tip of improvement, not the answer! Here's another tip - the general group by rule: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list should either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AND (bcp.value is null or bcp.value = cm.id)
```

Comment: Hi Zohar, Thanks for your prompt reply. However, if I do that, the column which that joint table was meant for gives me the wrong matching. The bcp.value  and cm.id are macthed so that the "Time completed" matches the items in cm (course modules)  I don't know how to show you the output here

Comment: Why? Just change the where, leave the join as is

Comment: If I do that, this is what I get: You can see on the last column the same dates appears twice                                                                          2015-06-29 03:28:38 2015-06-29 04:45:49
2015-06-29 03:28:38 2015-06-29 05:41:57
2015-06-29 03:33:55 2015-06-29 04:45:49
2015-06-29 03:33:55 2015-06-29 05:41:57

Comment: I can't understand anything from this output without a sample data and desired results to compare it to. Please cosnider creating a fiddle with some sample data and edit your question with desired results.

Comment: In order to get the "Time completed" right for an item, I need to match the time completed in mdl_badge_issued bgi with the items in mdl_course_modules. When I do that, those items arent in time completed table yet do not show up, of which I want them to show up. So when I put OR option the time completed does not match items vs time completed, does that make sense? sorry if i'm too ambigous

Comment: OK, will do that now, Thanks Zohar

Answer (score 1):

Just add `OR` Inside your Where Clause like this

`WHERE c.shortname = 'DOM_2015_1' AND (bcp.value = cm.id OR bcp.value IS NULL)`

or if it string `bcp.value = ""`

**Update**

Before to adding this in Where clause you have to get correct *Join* maybe it will be better use *FULL OUTER JOIN* or *RIGHT JOIN*(Is it possible? It depends on your logic) instead of using *LEFT JOIN*

Comment: Hi The, Thanks for your prompt reply. However, if I do that, the column which that joint table was meant for gives me the wrong matching. The bcp.value  and cm.id are macthed so that the "Time completed" matches the items in cm (course modules)  I don't know how to show you the output here

Comment: You can add this criteria to `ON` clause or instead of adding this you can change your `Left' to `Right` if it possible and you get All _Null_ records from your table

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` conditions are being applied to entire resultset, thus discarding any of those rows from table `mdl_course_modules_completion` that don't meet this criteria.

If you only need to check for `NULL` value that could come from `mdl_badge_criteria_param bcp` table, then adding additional `(or bcp.value is null)` would suffice.

This is because your `mdl_course_modules cm` table is being joined to `mdl_badge_criteria_param bcp`, and not the main table. If we had the case of joining directly with the main table, making `bcp` independent from `cm`, query could sometimes yield wrong results, when `cm.id` would be holding `NULL`, and `bcp.value` was a non-null value.

Keeping that in mind, your solution would be

```
WHERE c.shortname = 'DOM_2015_1' AND ( bcp.value = cm.id OR bcp.value is null )
```

**Edit** You may also consider dropping the entire condition considering `bcp.value = cm.id` since it seems like you want to allow every record, that has a matching `cm.id` with the main table to appear and instead applying a `cm.id is not null` to your where condition.

Comment: Hi Consider, you are correct. The reason I matched the mdl_course_modules cm and mdl_badge_criteria_param is because I wanted to get the correct date for that particular item from mdl_badge_issued bgi which is linked through mdl_badge_criteria_param. And if there is any item in mdl_course_modules not in mdl_badge_criteria_param yet it should show. If I use OR condition it means all data will be populated, however, the date won't match. Thanks, couldn't post the screenshot

Comment: Does the solution I suggested after Edit part work for you?

Comment: Hi Consider, Thanks! No, If I add that it still doesn't match the "Time completed" dates with the items.:(

Comment: Is there an option in sql to combine columns? I though of separating the column for the items that don't appear?

Comment: Time Completed column is totally independent of what what we are discussing here as far as I can see from your query. Attach sample result and expected result in your question, otherwise I'm unable to help.

Comment: I can't attach an image, it asks me for reputation points, do you know what that is?